# Does the bonus match include extra points rewarded?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Suppose that I get 1000 points as match bonus.

Suppose in free-for-all match I get 1 head shot. It's worth 200 points if my memory is good.

So, does the 1000 points rewarded include the head shot points ?

Did I get 1200 (1000 + 200) or only 1000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Match Bonus (I'm presuming that is what you mean) does not include points gained from headshots.

However, getting headshots does influence your match bonus. The main factor affecting it is whether you win, however.

Answer (score 1):

Winning is about 50% of the match bonus. Other important factors, if you take the time do a full multivariat regression is your K/D ratio, and the number of total kills amassed by your team.