# How is the match bonus in Modern Warfare 2 determined?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

At the end of a match, you get a match bonus, which is an extra reward of experience. I know it is influenced a lot by whether your team wins or loses, but does anyone know what factors go into calculating it?

Comment: The answers in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/does-the-bonus-match-include-extra-points-rewarded) talk about this a little bit, although not in much detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By far the largest contributing factor is whether or not your team wins or loses. I actually did a multivariate regression of almost a dozen factors about the game and two other largest contributing factors were your K/D ratio and your Team's Total Score (out of 10,000, 7,500, 200, what have you, depending on game type). Of course, your team winning and your team's total score may be auto-correlated (meaning that there is a correlation betweent the variables of Team Winning and Team Total Score). This means you could either remove Team Winning or Team Total Score and still have a valid model (depending on the degree of Auto-Correlation), but it would not have the same predictive power.

**Bottom Line**

Main Factors:

 - Your K/D

 - Your Team's Score

 - Your Team Wins Status

*Other Notes*

 - Total matches regressed: 34

 - Data does not appear to be heteroskedastic or homoskedastic

 - Correlation between Team Win and Team Total Score was 0.82

 - In the data set no draws occured

Comment: By chance is the data online?

Comment: Woah! That's a very well-researched answer.

Comment: They also seem to increase with your level.  The higher the level the bigger the match bonus.  Seems to start really being noticeable around level 35.  Was this a factor that you used?